# cocos2d-x 3.0 build_native.py fails

Tags: android, python, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have already installed cocos2d-x 3.0 and try to build an android version but when I run ./build_native.py, it was failed with error

```
File "./build_native.py", line 89, in do_build
    raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!")
Exception: Build dynamic library for project [ /Users/hoangha/Desktop/Enigma/cocos2d-x-3.0/projects/2048-enhanced-version/source/proj.android ] fails!
```

I have read the line 89 in the build_native.py

```
if os.system(command) != 0:
        raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!")
```

But I don't understand command os.system(command) in python, so can anybody help me to fix this error.

Comment: Isn't the problem with the command the script runs, ie the build failed rather than the contents of the build_native.py script? What's the (last couple lines of the) log on the screen, could you post that?

Comment: I'm sorry. I just thought it was not necessary. I have editted my post.

Comment: @HàLink I ran into the same issue. It seems like you may have solved this, if you did could you please share what you did?

Answer (score 0):

cocos2d-x 3.0 began to use `cocos run` commands to compile and run your project, the `build_native.py` script has not been maintained for a very long time. And it will be deprecated in the future.

If you created your project by using `cocos new` command, you can't rely on the `build_native.py` script.

If you want to build and run the tests bundled with cocos2d-x, you could use the `android-build.py` in the `build` directory of cocos2d-x root.

Answer (score 0):

The error hides in the log. In my case, it was a disk alert so `build_native.py` cannot write new file on disk.

```
/libcocos2dxinternal.a: No space left on device
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libcocos2dxinternal.a] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file 'obj/local/armeabi/libcocos2dxinternal.a'
/Users/xxxxx/Downloads/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ar: ./obj/local/armeabi/libcocostudio.a: No space left on device
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libbullet.a] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file 'obj/local/armeabi/libbullet.a'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libcocostudio.a] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file 'obj/local/armeabi/libcocostudio.a'
make: Leaving directory '/Users/xxxxx/Documents/android_projects/xxxxx/proj.android'
Error running command, return code: 2.
```

Log tells that there is no space left on device. So I delete unnecessary files and run the command again.